# I want take the last 4 record but always get the first 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this in my method:

```
var qry = db.Forms.Take(4)
                  .Where(m => m.SateliteID == Id)
                  .OrderByDescending(m => m.Tanggal)
                  .ToArray();
```

What I want is getting the last 4 records from all the records available, but
what I get is the first 4 records.
What I have done wrong?
I thought that command will be the same with this:

```
SELECT TOP 4 <fields> FROM Forms WHERE sateliteID = Id
ORDER BY tanggal DESC
```

But it seems they are a different.
What should I do to get what I want (the last 4 records instead of the first 4 records)?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think you should accept answer of @MarcinJuraszek because he is first one who gave the answer.......

Comment: I notice that he is the first, but I don't understand what he said, and after reading devdigital's answer, I just get what he mean. That's why I accept devdigital's answer and not MarcinJuraszek. May be because the example given in one line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move your Take:

```
var qry = db.Forms.Where(m => m.SateliteID == Id)
                 .OrderByDescending(m => m.Tanggal)
                 .Take(4)
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: aah, that easy? I never thought that the position of will affect the result as in SQL. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

```
var qry = db.Forms.Where(m => m.SateliteID == Id).OrderByDescending(m => m.Tanggal).Take(4).ToArray();
```

You should order and than take some results from ordered list. Methods should be called in that kind of order.

Answer (score 1):

JUST get apply you where and orderby clause first and than apply take function that will do the work for you

```
var qry = db.Forms
                      .Where(m => m.SateliteID == Id) 
                     .OrderByDescending(m => m.Tanggal) 
                     .Take(4)
                     .ToArray();
```

For future use :[LINQER](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

[image]

this will allow you to convert you SQL QUERIES TO LINQ easily.....very helpful tool

Comment: Thanks for the LINQER, I will use it.